# how to create an array of arrays in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to code a wordle clone using React, but the twist is that the player can choose the number of attempts and the length of the word. And i want to rendre the box depending on these two parameter so i used the following line :

`var grid = Array(this.props.nbrAttempts).fill(0).map(row => new Array(this.props.wordLenght).fill(' '))`

the first time the component render i get a 4*4 array, but after changing the parameter i get always a 1*1, and i can't figure what's the problem.

the Box component:

```
function App() {

  const [boxParam, setBoxParam] = useState({nbrAttempts: 4, wordLenght : 4,});
  

  let renderBox = ()=>{
    setBoxParam({
      nbrAttempts: document.getElementById('nbAttempts').value,
      wordLenght : document.getElementById('wordLength').value,
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      {/* add input field with number of attempts as label */}
      <label htmlFor="nbAttempts">Attempts</label>
      <input type="number" id="nbAttempts"/>

      <label htmlFor="nbAttempts">Word length</label>
      <input type="number" id="wordLength"/>

      <button onClick={()=>renderBox()}>OK</button>
      
      <Box nbrAttempts={boxParam.nbrAttempts} wordLenght={boxParam.wordLenght}  />
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: In general, you don't want to read values from the document like you do here. Keep those variables in state instead. In React, you typically control the shape of data, and render the view based on that. Add two more useStates for the input fields, and then just read those variables when you want to calculate the size of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced

```
var grid = Array(this.props.nbrAttempts).fill(0).map(row => new Array(this.props.wordLenght).fill(' '))
```

with

```
let grid = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < this.props.nbrAttempts; i++) {
        grid.push(new Array(this.props.wordLenght).fill('_'));
      }
```

and everything just worked fine